# Stuck on create symlink at /etc/service/kibana to /etc/sv/kibana when running kitchen test on CentOS 6.7

Tags: ruby, apache, chef-infra, cookbook, test-kitchen

my problem here is I got stuck on the kibana create symlink instead of continue running on the the code below which is elasticsearch recipe and logstash recipe. Can anybody know why this is happening cause I don't have any idea whats going on about this issue. Thanks Guys :) Happy coding...

my metadata.rb

```
depends 'java'
depends 'elasticsearch'
depends 'kibana_lwrp'
depends 'ucarp'
depends 'python'
```

my recipes/default.rb

```
include_recipe 'java'
include_recipe 'kibana_lwrp::install'
include_recipe 'my_elkstack::elasticsearch'
include_recipe 'my_elkstack::logstash'
```

This is the logs:

```
Recipe: kibana_lwrp::install
     * runit_service[kibana] action enable
       * ruby_block[restart_service] action nothing (skipped due to action :nothing)
       * ruby_block[restart_log_service] action nothing (skipped due to action :nothing)
       * directory[/etc/sv/kibana] action create
         - create new directory /etc/sv/kibana
         - change mode from '' to '0755'
       * template[/etc/sv/kibana/run] action create
         - create new file /etc/sv/kibana/run
         - update content in file /etc/sv/kibana/run from none to f0df85
         --- /etc/sv/kibana/run 2016-09-20 05:44:45.352159387 +0000
         +++ /etc/sv/kibana/.chef-run20160920-128-15s890o   2016-09-20 05:44:45.352159387 +0000
         @@ -1 +1,8 @@
         +#!/bin/sh
         +
         +cd /opt/kibana/current
         +exec 2>&1
         +
         +exec chpst -u kibana /opt/kibana/current/bin/kibana
         +
         - change mode from '' to '0755'
       * directory[/etc/sv/kibana/log] action create
         - create new directory /etc/sv/kibana/log
       * directory[/etc/sv/kibana/log/main] action create
         - create new directory /etc/sv/kibana/log/main
         - change mode from '' to '0755'
       * directory[/var/log/kibana] action create
         - create new directory /var/log/kibana
         - change mode from '' to '0755'
       * template[/etc/sv/kibana/log/config] action create
         - create new file /etc/sv/kibana/log/config
         - update content in file /etc/sv/kibana/log/config from none to e3b0c4
         (no diff)
         - change mode from '' to '0644'
       * link[/var/log/kibana/config] action create
         - create symlink at /var/log/kibana/config to /etc/sv/kibana/log/config
       * template[/etc/sv/kibana/log/run] action create
         - create new file /etc/sv/kibana/log/run
         - update content in file /etc/sv/kibana/log/run from none to e64148
         --- /etc/sv/kibana/log/run 2016-09-20 05:44:45.368159387 +0000
         +++ /etc/sv/kibana/log/.chef-run20160920-128-punoc6    2016-09-20 05:44:45.368159387 +0000
         @@ -1 +1,3 @@
         +#!/bin/sh
         +exec svlogd -tt ./main
         - change mode from '' to '0755'
       * directory[/etc/sv/kibana/env] action create
         - create new directory /etc/sv/kibana/env
         - change mode from '' to '0755'
       * ruby_block[zap extra env files for kibana service] action run (skipped due to only_if)
       * template[/etc/sv/kibana/check] action create (skipped due to only_if)
       * template[/etc/sv/kibana/finish] action create (skipped due to only_if)
       * directory[/etc/sv/kibana/control] action create
         - create new directory /etc/sv/kibana/control
         - change mode from '' to '0755'
       * link[/etc/init.d/kibana] action create
         - create symlink at /etc/init.d/kibana to /sbin/sv
       * file[/etc/sv/kibana/down] action nothing (skipped due to action :nothing)
       * ruby_block[restart_service] action run
         * ruby_block[restart_service] action nothing (skipped due to action :nothing)
         * ruby_block[restart_log_service] action nothing (skipped due to action :nothing)
         * directory[/etc/sv/kibana] action create (up to date)
         * template[/etc/sv/kibana/run] action create (up to date)
         * directory[/etc/sv/kibana/log] action create (up to date)
         * directory[/etc/sv/kibana/log/main] action create (up to date)
         * directory[/var/log/kibana] action create (up to date)
         * template[/etc/sv/kibana/log/config] action create (up to date)
         * link[/var/log/kibana/config] action create (up to date)
         * template[/etc/sv/kibana/log/run] action create (up to date)
         * directory[/etc/sv/kibana/env] action create (up to date)
         * ruby_block[zap extra env files for kibana service] action run (skipped due to only_if)
         * template[/etc/sv/kibana/check] action create (skipped due to only_if)
         * template[/etc/sv/kibana/finish] action create (skipped due to only_if)
         * directory[/etc/sv/kibana/control] action create (up to date)
         * link[/etc/init.d/kibana] action create (up to date)
         * file[/etc/sv/kibana/down] action nothing (skipped due to action :nothing)
         * directory[/etc/service] action create (up to date)
         * link[/etc/service/kibana] action create
    - create symlink at /etc/service/kibana to /etc/sv/kibana
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This usually means `runsvdir` isn't picking up the new service. Check that Runit itself has started correctly from whatever the system init daemon is.